# Can we use GitHub CodeSpaces for SWI-Prolog?

Tags: swi-prolog, github-codespaces

I have just been looking at GitHub CodeSpaces, and am interested to know if we can use it for SWI-Prolog in the same way we can use Visual Studio Code.

In VSC, I installed the SWI-Prolog extension, and made sure my PATH included the SWI-Prolog install folder, then I can code in Prolog in VSC.

However, I can't see how to get GitHub CodeSpaces to know about SWI-Prolog. There seem to be options to configure the code space, but I can't see how to install SWI-Prolog .

Anyone able to help? Thanks.